# tableexport plugin giving Uncaught TypeError: o is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i'm using `tableexport` plugin https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport

i'm getting this error

> error  Uncaught TypeError: o is not a function(…)

i have made jsfiddle please click 4 times on `EXPORT EXCEL` so that the `icon` will appear

please check the `console` for error

here is **demo**:https://jsfiddle.net/gmd3xctt/12/

why this error is coming i don't know.

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: i have included this 2 cdn's   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/3.3.7/js/tableexport.min.js  AND    https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Base64/1.0.0/base64.min.js

Comment: I don't think you are looking at the correct documentation. Here is [documentation](https://tableexport.v4.travismclarke.com/) for the [TableExport](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport) plugin by [clarketm](https://github.com/clarketm).

Comment: @TravisClarke I have included both FileSaver and TableExport from your site and the problem is still there. It says a.formats.foreach is not a function

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem
According to the documentation on : https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin.

download and add call https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.min.js

above 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="tableExport.min.js"></script>`
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You are including files incorrectly. Please follow below order and it will work.

```
<script src="path_to/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="path_to/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>
```

Note that FileSaver.min.js must be included before tableexport.js

Hope it will help.

Cheers